# How to create application which displays calendar events in timeline view for daily and weekly bases?

Tags: ios, events, icalendar, timeline, eventkit

Is there any code or library available to develop such an application which displays calendar events in week view or daily view or yearly view according to requirement?

Requirement is the code should be in such a generalize format that it can compatible with all 3 conditions to plot events and display them.

Also that code/library should care about the overlapping events or over-day events.

Please guide me on this. I am completely blank for EventKit framework and such a designing.

Thanks in advance.

Mrunal

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, there are some calendar frameworks available. Please have look here

[CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

[Tapku](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) // Seem  to be one of the best one, try seeing its demo.

-anoop